# Laravel 8 validation for image can get old input after symbolic link

Tags: laravel, image, validation, upload

Using Laravel 8, I thought when I used to return a form on a validation error, I could load all the old inputs back into the view using the `{{old('fieldname')}}` helper.

However, that has stopped returning the inputs for my file upload input boxes, everything else returns to the form as normal, except the image inputs.

```php
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'front_image' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:3000',      
    'back_image'  => 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:3000|required', 
    'indentured' => 'required|in:yes,no',
    'trade_selection' => ''
]);
```

When I use `{{ old('front_image) }}` nothing is reported.  Weird thing is I can receive the errors for the input, and if I allow the form to push through I can see the files with `dd($request)` under files.

Comment: you can not use ``old`` on file type form fields. It doesn;t work for that.

Comment: `old()` is not compatible with `<input type="file"`, as they do not have a `value=""` parameter. The User will need to re-select the image or file on validation redirect.

Comment: @superdj if you edit a question to add code fences, please also remove the indent!